# Rails & Devise fields validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I added :first_name and :last_name fields to my User model, and I added this line:

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
```

Now, this works when I use omniauth scenario, where I initialize my User object  with
new_with_session function. However when I attempt just regular email & confirmation
registration - although I fill the form fields necessary, I get validation errors -

**First name can't be blank**

**Last name can't be blank**

In omniauth scenario i use new_with_session with this code:

```
    super.tap do |user|
                user.attributes = session["devise.user_data"]              
                user.password = params["password"]
                user.password_confirmation = params["password_confirmation"]
```

- which pre-fills the registration form with received first & last name from oauth provider.
  In this case it all goes well, with registration.

However, I even tried removing first & last name from the form fields in this scenario (new_with_session),
but the registration still succeeds, without raising validation issues.

What am I missing?

I tried commenting out the new_with_session completely, and even removing the omniauth module,
but it still gives me false validation errors.

When I sign up with facebook, for example, and new_with_session, it works.

These are the form fields in erb:

```
  <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %></div>
```

Here is a screenshot with POST in firebug & issue in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a more detailed pic of the errors?

Comment: I think it is pretty clear.
I get validation errors as if I didnt enter the first_name and last_name.
When I did.

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: did you make sure to whitelist the params?

Comment: Im not sure how to go around doing that, since large part of that is handled by devise controllers & code.

Should I apply it with generalized new_with_session that uses needed params and applies them to initialize new User, or should I downright override User update & create actions?

Comment: Btw, I believe you nailed the issue.
I missed that.